# Is it possible in Fortran to assign procedure name at run time in a type bound procedure?

Tags: pointers, interface, fortran

I discovered type-bound procedures and was wondering how I could use them. I have this code which is working as expected:

```
module utils
implicit none
type TypeParam
  integer :: val
  contains
    procedure :: initval  => initI
    procedure :: writeval => writeI
end type TypeParam
contains
!---------------------------
  subroutine initI(this,val)
  class(TypeParam),intent(inout)::this
  integer,intent(in) :: val
  
  this%val=val

  end subroutine initI
!---------------------------  
  subroutine writeI(this)
  class(TypeParam),intent(inout)::this
  
  print*,this%val

  end subroutine writeI      
!---------------------------  
end module utils

program testtypebound
use utils
implicit none
type(TypeParam) :: TP(2)

call TP(1)%initval(3)
call TP(2)%initval(5)
call TP(1)%writeval() ! Returns 3
call TP(2)%writeval() ! Returns 5

end program testtypebound
```

Now I do not know how, if it makes any sense at all, to assign initval and writeval at runtime. Having them point to null() and assign them in the main program as TP(1)%initval=>othersubroutine.

The following code, which does not use type-bound procedure, does what I want, not sure though if it the way to go. Are there any pitfalls to the second approach ?

Many thanks

```
module utils
implicit none
type TypeParam
  integer :: val
  procedure(InitValInteger),  pointer :: initval  => null()
  procedure(WriteValInteger), pointer :: writeval => null()
end type TypeParam

interface
  subroutine InitValInteger(this,val)
  import TypeParam
  class(TypeParam),intent(inout)::this
  integer,intent(in) :: val
  end subroutine InitValInteger

  subroutine WriteValInteger(this)
  import TypeParam  
  class(TypeParam),intent(inout)::this  
  end subroutine WriteValInteger  
end interface

contains
!---------------------------
  subroutine initI(this,val)
  class(TypeParam),intent(inout)::this
  integer,intent(in) :: val
  
  this%val=val

  end subroutine initI
!---------------------------  
  subroutine writeI(this)
  class(TypeParam),intent(inout)::this
  
  print*,this%val

  end subroutine writeI      
!---------------------------  
end module utils

program testtypebound
use utils
implicit none
type(TypeParam) :: TP(2)

TP(1)%initval =>initI
TP(1)%writeval=>writeI
TP(2)%initval =>initI
TP(2)%writeval=>writeI
call TP(1)%initval(3) 
call TP(2)%initval(5)
call TP(1)%writeval() ! Returns 3
call TP(2)%writeval() ! Returns 5

end program testtypebound
```

**Clarification**

As pointed out in the comments, the previous examples may not be useful. Here is a code which I think does what I want and could be extended to my real code:

```
module utils
implicit none
type TypeParam
  integer :: val
  procedure(UseValue),  pointer :: useval  => null()
end type TypeParam

interface
  real*8 function UseValue(this,i)
  import TypeParam
  class(TypeParam),intent(inout)::this
  integer,intent(in) :: i
  end function UseValue
end interface
contains
!---------------------------
  real*8 function useval1(this,i)
  class(TypeParam),intent(inout)::this
  integer,intent(in) :: i
  
  useval1=this%val+i

  end function useval1
!---------------------------
  real*8 function useval2(this,i)
  class(TypeParam),intent(inout)::this
  integer,intent(in) :: i
  
  useval2=this%val**2+i

  end function useval2         
!---------------------------  
end module utils

program testtypebound
use utils
implicit none
integer :: i
type(TypeParam) :: TP

write(*,*) "Enter version 1 or 2"
read(*,*) i

if(i==1)then
  TP%val=2
  TP%useval =>useval1
elseif(i==2)then  
  TP%val=1
  TP%useval =>useval2
else
  write(*,*) "Version unknown (1 or 2)"
  stop  
endif
print*, TP%useval(2) ! Returns 4 if i=1 and 3 if i=2

end program testtypebound
```

But before I start to implement this, does this code have drawbacks, flaws? Can it be made simpler/more compact using type-bound procedures ? In real life, TP will be an array, such that each component of the array will hold different procedures depending on user input.

Comment: "Now I do not know how, if it makes any sense at all, to assign initval and writeval at runtime." This depends on how you want to use these procedures. In the example program you show, it makes very little sense to do this, but in other cases it makes a lot of sense. How general/flexible do you wish to be?

Comment: @fracescalus Thanks. I am not sure how to explain better without posting another longer example. I want to be able to point to one or an other subroutine depending on user input choice. Subroutines will have the same arguments but will do different things. These subroutines will depend on varying arguments as well as values hosted in the derived type. The whole point is to avoid using conditionals throughout the code and use a generic name for the subroutine. Do you think code 2 is acceptable ?

Comment: Well, you can always use function pointers, exactly as you do in your last example. But function pointers are not the same as type-bound procedures. So, is your actual question about what you did in the sample at the end? Whether the solution with function pointers is feasible? It is very different from what you show in the first part of your post.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I discovered type-bound procedures not so long ago and found it elegant but I feel I do not get yet the power of it. So naively I thought I could use it for my aim, but I need to be able to assign/reassign procedures at runtime. After some trials and search I don't know if is possible, or if it is against the philosophy of it. I am ok with last example after the CLARIFICATION, just wondering if it is safe/robust/standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type-bound procedures are "bound to a derived type and referenced via an object of that type" (Fortran 2018, 3.112.6). Being bound to a *type* and not an *object* means that two objects of the same type result in the same reference. (Further, the definition of a type cannot change during execution.)

A procedure pointer component is different: it's a component of the type and each object instance of the type can have its own value and, for a variable, its value can change during execution.

Which mechanism best suits a use case depends on what is required. If you want two objects of the same type to resolve to different procedure references, or want the referenced procedure to vary during execution, you'll be using procedure pointer components.

A procedure pointer can be not-associated and there's no equivalent state for a type-bound procedure. This means you have a responsibility to ensure that `call a%s()` has the `s` procedure pointer component pointer associated with a target, but also allows you to do logic like `if (ASSOCIATED(a%s)) ...` (if it's of defined association status). You're also responsible for ensuring it always points to the place you want it to point (note also that one can't PROTECT components) and for ease you may well end up writing a structure constructor.

Equally, a procedure pointer component can be used in ways a binding name cannot be: `call run(a%s)` is allowed for a procedure pointer component, but not for a type-bound procedure.

That said, the use case of referencing based on a run-time condition can be addressed even using type-bound procedures:

```
type t
  logical :: use_a = .TRUE.
 contains
  procedure :: selector
end type t
```

where `selector` is a wrapper like

```
subroutine selector(this, val)
  class(t), intent(in) :: this
  integer, intent(in) :: val

  if (this%use_a) then
    call A(this, val)
  else
    call B(this, val)
  end if
end subroutine selector
```